# changing behavior on drag/drop in Slack?

Tags: file-upload, slack-api, slack

Does the Slack API provide the ability to change the action taken when drag/dropping a file? Basically, I'd like to have files automatically uploaded to Google Drive instead of Slack when dropped into the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You can't prevent the upload to Slack and redirect it somehow. The only thing you could do is use the API to check which files have been uploaded already (e.g. using [`files.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.list)) and then upload them to Google Drive.

Comment: Could I automate the upload using the Google Drive API within a slack app or integration, and then delete the files from Slack?

Comment: Probably, but it would be awkward because users would see their files appear and later disappear, and if they post something in between, your app would post the new Google Drive link probably after their new messages, etc. - It would get very messy.

Comment: Very true. Thank you.